# how to fix value of textbox using asp.net

Tags: textbox

I have textbox named txtchild. I want it takes only two digits no. and when user enters more than two digits no it gives an error message.

please help

Comment: instead of message why not you restrict user to enter upto only 2 digit? like below code

<asp:TextBox ID="txtchild" runat="server" MaxLength="2"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void txtchild_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
      if(txtchild.Text.lenght>2)
       {
        e.Handled = true;
       }
      else
       {
          MessageBox.Show("Value must be Two digit");
       }
    }
```